# inflammatory and anti-inflammatory food table

Tags: injury, injury-prevention, food

To avoid sports injuries anyone knows if exists (book, ebook, internet..) a nutritional table (detected by recent scientific studies) that lists the inflammatory and anti-inflammatory power of each food ? What food should be avoided to reduce sports injuries and what food should be preferred to reduce sports injuries .

Evidence publications

Total antioxidant capacity of plant foods, beverages and oils consumed in Italy assessed by three different in vitro assays. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12949370

Vegetables, fruit, antioxidants and cancer: a review of Italian studies.
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11876489

Total antioxidant capacity of the diet is inversely and independently related to plasma concentration of high-sensitivity C-reactive protein in adult Italian subjects.
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15975160

Free radical mechanisms in dementia of Alzheimer type and the potential for antioxidative treatment.  https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/7763342

Screening of dietary carotenoids and carotenoid-rich fruit extracts for antioxidant activities applying 2,2′-azinobis(3-ethylenebenzothiazoline-6-sulfonic acid radical cation decolorization assay
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0076687999990377?via%3Dihub

A fluorescence-based method for measuring total plasma antioxidant capability.
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/7896168

Ferric reducing antioxidant power assay: direct measure of total antioxidant activity of biological fluids and modified version for simultaneous measurement of total antioxidant power and ascorbic acid concentration.
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0076687999990055?via%3Dihub

Food selection based on total antioxidant capacity can modify antioxidant intake, systemic inflammation, and liver function without altering markers of oxidative stress.
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18469252

The total antioxidant content of more than 3100 foods, beverages, spices, herbs and supplements used worldwide.
https://nutritionj.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1475-2891-9-3

Comment: Welcome to the forum. You will have received these down-votes, I think, because you first need to demonstrate evidence (1) that inflammatory and anti-inflammatory foods exist and are measurable, and (2) that such properties are associated specifically with sports injuries, as opposed to inflammatory illnesses, for example. It is generally assumed that sports injuries are caused by the combination of chronic over-training and the acute (mis-) application of loads.

Comment: I'm adding some evidence study now.

Comment: BTW this https://nutritionj.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1475-2891-9-3 partially replies to my question since it lists only antioxidant foods but I would know and food which should be avoided which increase body inflammation.

Comment: Okay, so we have established (1) that inflammatory and anti-inflammatory foods exist, but not (2) their link with the sports injuries. Do you know of any evidence that suggests that they are connected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anti-inflammatory foods are important for mitigating fatigue, and fatigue is an important factor in injury causation- [source 1](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/8775109/), [source 2](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-0-387-72577-2_4#:~:text=During%20a%20maximum%20contraction%20of,fatigue%20(Rothwell%2C%201994).)

Here's a list of [3100 foods](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2841576/) listed by antioxidant content.

Antioxidants have different antiinflammatory properties but it seems the strongest are plant pigments such ascarotenoids and anthocyanins.